# How to prove that I did not receive a payment

Tags: money-transfer, online-banking, online-payment, payment, wire-transfer

I'm working with an online company that sends payments through a bank.

I sent them a payment request a while ago with my IBAN + the bank SWIFT and other details provided, so they could transfer the money to my personal account. unfortunately I did not receive the money.

Upon contacting them, they inform me that they sent the payment. how can I prove to them that I did not receive anything? or how can I prove that they really send the payment? ... is there for example a transaction ID that I can use for these situations?

Comment: Are they asking you to prove that you didn't receive a payment. Or is that just an idea you came up with for a way to resolve the problem?

Comment: Maybe they *did* send the payment... to the *wrong* account.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, No... they didn't ask me to prove anything... it's just my idea to resolve the problem

Comment: @RonJohn, I've checked the details that I sent multiple times (IBAN, SWIFT, etc...) I'm sure it's correct + they send a screenshot of a successful payment with my IBAN in it.

Comment: @NezarAli then I'd go to your bank with that screen shot.

Comment: proving the absence of something is typically a difficult trick....

Comment: @NezarAli In the future, keep in mind that you will get better answers to your questions if you ask about the problem you have, rather than the way you think you should solve it. If you look at what people will see first in your question, "*How to prove that I did not receive a payment*", that is about how you think you should solve it, not about the problem itself. People who may know exactly how to solve your problem may not realize it when they look at the question because the question gives them no clue what the problem is. See [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem) for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inform the company that you didn't receive the payment. Only they can trace the payment via their bank.

Answer (score 1):

Show your Bank passbook, preferably signed one, to relevant money sender.

Comment: Very few bank accounts, worldwide, offer passbooks any more. And haven't for decades.

Comment: They still have. Mode had been changed to online, though.